# c# 3rd parties on skype

Tags: c#, skype

I have an application that wants to communicate with skype using skype4com. Everytime i run skype.attach(6,false) in skype pops up a message saying that app.exe wants to conect with u. Allow it or no? Is there a way I can programatically allow the app.exe to attach to skype?

Answer (score 3):

For security reasons, this message will always pop up to alert the Skype user that a third-party program wants to attach. However, it should only happen once per application. Are you recompiling each time?